# Why is LocalTimeToUniversal(Now) two hours later with Lazarus 1.6 / FPC 3.0?

Tags: datetime, utc, lazarus, fpc

My local time zone is UTC+1, so when it is 16:30 here, this line

```
ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(LocalTimeToUniversal(Now)));
```

displays the correct value "12.12.2015 15:30" with Lazarus 1.4.2 / Free Pascal 2.6.4.

With Free Pascal 3.0.0 (Lazarus 1.6RC1) it displays "12.12.2015 17:30", two hours later. Do I miss something in the migration from FPC 2.6 to 3.0, or is it a bug?

In both cases, GetLocalTimeOffset returns -60.

Comment: Looks like a bug
http://free-pascal-general.1045716.n5.nabble.com/UniversalTimeToLocal-UT-TDateTime-LocalTimeToUniversal-LT-TDateTime-td5722054.html

Comment: Maybe their runtime library needs some unit tests too.

Comment: Probably the FPC/Lazarus team changed direction of Earth rotation to the opposite.

Comment: Reported as http://mantis.freepascal.org/view.php?id=29176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the Free Pascal 3.0.0 RTL.

freepascal bugtracker: http://mantis.freepascal.org/view.php?id=29176

(update: it is fixed in 3.1.1, target version is 3.0.2)